# Customizing angular filter functionality

Tags: angularjs

I am struggling in writing simple logic. 
Please have a look and see if you can help me.

I have following code which shows three tables on UI at the moment based on data im returning from server.

I have search box which filter data in each table. It is also working fine.

**My requirement:**
I need to show one generic message "No data found" when no data found in all three tables based on input.

```
<div>
 <input type="text" ng-model="searchStudent">
<div>
    <div ng-repeat="studentPermissions in studentPermissions">
        <div ng-repeat="student in studentPermissions.entities">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td >Student</td>
                        <td>{{student.StudentName}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th ng-repeat="permission in student.entityStudents[0].userPermissions"><div><span>{{permission.Name}}</span></div></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="student in student.entityStudents | filter:searchStudent">
                        <td>{{student.FirstName}} {{student.LastName}}</td>
                        <td ng-repeat="permission in student.userPermissions">
                            <input ng-model="permission.Checked" type="checkbox">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have written `search` method in controller.

```
    $scope.search = function (item) {
        if ($scope.searchUser == null || $scope.searchStudent.trim() == "")
            return true;
        if (item.FirstName.toLowerCase().indexOf($scope.searchStudent.toLowerCase()) != -1 || item.LastName.toLowerCase().indexOf($scope.searchStudent.toLowerCase()) != -1 || item.Role.toLowerCase().indexOf($scope.searchStudent.toLowerCase()) != -1) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    };
```

I tried by setting flag on /off tricks but each time ended up something wrong.

My Sample Data:

```
$scope.studentPermissions  = [ 
{entities[{StudentName: 'Tester', entityStudents[{FirstName: 'Test0', LastName: 'Test0', userPermissions[{prop 1, prop2, prop3}]}]}]},
{entities[{StudentName: 'Tester', entityStudents[{FirstName: 'Test1', LastName: 'Test2', userPermissions[{prop 1, prop2, prop3}]}]}]},
{entities[{StudentName: 'Tester', entityStudents[{FirstName: 'Test3', LastName: 'Test4', userPermissions[{prop 1, prop2, prop3}]}]}]},
]
```

Comment: Which 3 tables are you talking about? I only see one table in the posted code. Do you want to know when the filtered student collection is empty?

Comment: @ JB Nizet, There is an outer ng-repeat i.e. <div ng-repeat="student in studentPermissions.entities"> .. so no of tables depends on outer ng-repeat. with my current data i have 3 tables being created on UI.

Comment: @immirza there is one filter in your code - filter:searchStudent. Based on this you want to show that generic message?

Comment: Hi did the update work for you?

Comment: @ jme11 not really i am trying to create plnkr for you with exact data so you can figure out properly. i will revert soon.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ngIf/ngShow/ngHide/ngClass for this, but you have to slightly change the way you write your repeat.  For example, you can write it like this:

```
ng-repeat="student in filteredData = (student.entityStudents | filter:searchStudent)">
```

You can also do:

```
ng-repeat="student in student.entityStudents | filter:searchStudent as filteredData"
```

So, now you have a reference to the filteredData and you can just use filteredData.length in your ngShow/Hide/If/Class as the boolean.  If it's length is 0 it will be falsy:

```
<p ng-hide="filteredData.length">No Data Found</p>
```

Here's a working demo, which I think matches your requirements, as best I can tell.  Note that I moved your filter to the first nested repeat so that the tables were fully hidden if they didn't match and you only have one "No Data Found" message.

## Updated [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ucE4EQ0mDmNmcLi8ONYU?p=preview)

Comment: this is fine but the problem is it shows repeated messages. If you see in my code i have an outer ng-repeat <div ng-repeat="student in studentPermissions.entities"> which creates multiple tables. so, <p ng-hide="filteredData.length">No Data Found</p> is repeated for each iteration of outerloop. did you get my point? Whereas i need to display message only once if no data found in every table.

Comment: I think you're missing the point.  You don't have to use the filteredData inside the repeat.  It's like any other variable.  You can use it where you want to on the page.  If you want to hide the whole table when the results are empty, no problem, just add an ng-hide to the table, or add a class with ngClass.  Will do an example for you.

Comment: @ jme11, ooh i though the scope of filterData is just inside outer ng-repeat..i was not aware that it can be accessed be anywhere in html file.  Earlier i was using <div ng-show="!(student.entityStudents | filter:searchStudent).length"> outside the outer ng-repeat scope but it was not working. So what i understood, filterData  is just global variable? right?

Comment: Here, I just modified one of the demos from the doc: http://plnkr.co/edit/ucE4EQ0mDmNmcLi8ONYU?p=preview.

Comment: something wrong as i still can't access filteredData outside ng-repeat... no idea why.. i dont have <body> in my html my html as <divs> only

Comment: Well, not technically a global.  You can't use it "anywhere" on the page.  I should have written that better.  You can use it anywhere in the same scope.  So if you have two separately scoped controllers on the page and the repeat is in one, you can use it within that view only, not within the other controller's scoped view.

Comment: @ jme11 ok.. not sure what is different in my case have to check,,but is there a way i can set flag when the message is shown for the first time and than don't show message for other repeats?

Comment: would be nice if you can update you answer for firstrun logic?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82398/discussion-between-immirza-and-jme11).